# Find difference in two different data-frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frame df1 is 26000 rows, df2 is 25000 rows.
Im trying to find data points that are in d1 but not in d2, vice versa.
This is what I wrote (below code) but when I cross check it shows me shared data point

```
import pandas as pd 
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')

df_join = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1).drop_duplicates(keep = FALSE)

only_df1 = df_join.loc[df_join[df2.columns.to_list()].isnull().all(axis = 1), df1.columns.to_list()]
```

Order doesn't matter just want to know whether that data point exist in one or the other data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two dfs:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'b': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]})
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

```
   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  3  1
3  4  1
4  5  1
```

```
   a  b
0  2  1
1  3  1
2  4  1
3  5  1
4  6  1
```

You could do:

```
df_differences = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True)

print(df_differences)
```

Result:

```
   a  b      _merge
0  1  1   left_only
1  2  1        both
2  3  1        both
3  4  1        both
4  5  1        both
5  6  1  right_only
```

And then:

```
only_df1 = df_differences[df_differences['_merge'].eq('left_only')].drop(columns=['_merge'])
only_df2 = df_differences[df_differences['_merge'].eq('right_only')].drop(columns=['_merge'])

print(only_df1)
print()
print(only_df2)
```

```
   a  b
0  1  1

   a  b
5  6  1
```

Comment: @EmilyNwo yes, aren't they already dataframes? Like `df1` and `df2` in your question. My dataframes are just examples, you should use your own.

Comment: This is great, it's what I was looking for. Thank you! Really appreciate your help
And to your comment, yes they are already in dataframes but my lab uses r to do some pre-processing when we get our  data bc python doesn't have bio packages (not that much at least in comparison to R what we need).